# Strange exception Facebook iOS sdk

Tags: ios, facebook

Request:

```
- (void) getMyImageWithContestOfFace{
currentApiCall = getMyImageFb;
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"SELECT pic FROM user WHERE uid=me()",@"query",
                               nil];
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[delegate facebook] requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query"
                                 andParams:params
                             andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                               andDelegate:self];
}
```

Parsing:

```
...
case getMyImageFb:{
        flag = TRUE;
         imageWithFace = [[UIImage alloc] init];
         imageWithFace = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[result objectForKey:@"pic"]]]];
        }
        break;
...
```

When i call it i catch very strange exeption:

*2011-11-10 00:30:30.661 FaceGraph[1699:f803] I have some information
2011-11-10 00:30:30.664 FaceGraph[1699:f803] -[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d3d470
2011-11-10 00:30:30.666 FaceGraph[1699:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d3d470'**
 First throw call stack:
(0x15d9052 0x176ad0a 0x15daced 0x153ff00 0x153fce2 0x254db 0xb6d6 0xbcf7 0xc9ba59 0xc99e94 0xc9aeb7 0xc99e4f 0xc99fd5 0xbdef6a 0x3b8bbbd 0x3c585ea 0x3b82298 0x3c5816b 0x3b82137 0x15ad97f 0x1510b73 0x1510454 0x150fdb4 0x150fccb 0x14c2879 0x14c293e 0x2a6a9b 0x2332 0x22a5)
terminate called throwing an exceptionsharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c

No idea why. The most strange that i did it before ABSOLUTELY the same, and it worked fine.
I can't find the difference between my old projects and current. Maybe somebody have the same problem?? If you need more code - ask for it.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the exception seems to be quite clear: `result` is probably an array and not a dictionary.

PS: The line `imageWithFace = [[UIImage alloc] init];` is totally superfluous given the line that follows it. You should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add:

```
if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
    result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

in result-parsing function.